# CNN media:content medium="image" SyndicationFeed

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, syndication-feed

I'm trying to get the image value out of CNN's RSS feed, but I'm having problems trying to get it.

What I after is the value from

```xml
 <media:content medium="image" 
                url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180513143656-police-masks-surabaya-hp-video.jpg" 
                height="144" 
                width="256" />
```

With the code below I can see what I'm after, but I just cannot retrieve the value.

```cs
foreach (SyndicationElementExtension extension in f.ElementExtensions)
{
    XElement element = extension.GetObject<XElement>();
    if (element.HasAttributes)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes())
        {
             //How to get value here    
        }
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve the image value?

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by using Linq.

```
  var urlElem = element.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "url");
  if(urlElem!=null)
  {
     Console.Write(urlElem.Value);
  }
```

Dont forget the using:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Comment: Even easier: `element.Attribute("url");`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stay close to what you have this will list all url's from the medium="image" in an CNN rss feed:

```
var ns = (XNamespace) "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";  // namespace of the extension

SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create(@"http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss"));

var urls = from item in feed.Items              // all items
           from ext in  item.ElementExtensions  // all extensions to ext
           where ext.OuterName == "group" &&    // find the ones called group
                 ext.OuterNamespace == ns       // in the right namespace
           from content in ext.GetObject<XElement>().Elements(ns + "content") // get content elements
           where (string) content.Attribute("medium") == "image"  // if that medium is an image
           select (string) content.Attribute("url");              // get the url

// output what is in urls
foreach(string url in urls) 
{
      Console.WriteLine(url);
}
```

Most significant is that `GetObject<XElement>()` did give you the `group` element but that element by it self doesn't have the attributes `medium` and `url`. You have to enumerate the children named `content` and each of those elements does have the attributes you're interested in.

If you need the width and height as well, you can easily project them in the final select:

```
select new { 
            url = (string) content.Attribute("url"),
            h = (int) content.Attribute("height"),
            w = (int) content.Attribute("width") 
           };
```

Answer (score -1):

The items do not have any values.  Here is a sample of the xml :

```
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[Trump says he's working with China to save tech firm crushed by US ban]]></title>
      <link>http://money.cnn.com/2018/05/13/technology/business/trump-zte-corporation-china-commerce/index.html</link>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://money.cnn.com/2018/05/13/technology/business/trump-zte-corporation-china-commerce/index.html</guid>
      <pubDate>Sun, 13 May 2018 22:38:18 GMT</pubDate>
      <media:group>
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-super-169.jpg" height="619" width="1100" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-large-11.jpg" height="300" width="300" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-vertical-large-gallery.jpg" height="552" width="414" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-video-synd-2.jpg" height="480" width="640" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-live-video.jpg" height="324" width="576" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-t1-main.jpg" height="250" width="250" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-vertical-gallery.jpg" height="360" width="270" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-story-body.jpg" height="169" width="300" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-t1-main.jpg" height="250" width="250" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-assign.jpg" height="186" width="248" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510091942-zte-office-shanghai-hp-video.jpg" height="144" width="256" />
      </media:group>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[US officials offer North Korea 'prosperity' for de-nuking]]></title>
      <link>https://www.cnn.com/collections/north-korea-intl-051318/</link>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">https://www.cnn.com/collections/north-korea-intl-051318/</guid>
      <pubDate>Sun, 13 May 2018 18:36:04 GMT</pubDate>
      <media:group>
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-super-169.jpg" height="619" width="1100" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-large-11.jpg" height="300" width="300" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-vertical-large-gallery.jpg" height="552" width="414" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-video-synd-2.jpg" height="480" width="640" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-live-video.jpg" height="324" width="576" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-t1-main.jpg" height="250" width="250" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-vertical-gallery.jpg" height="360" width="270" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-story-body.jpg" height="169" width="300" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-t1-main.jpg" height="250" width="250" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-assign.jpg" height="186" width="248" />
        <media:content medium="image" url="https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180510111120-20180510-trump-kim-illo-01-hp-video.jpg" height="144" width="256" />
      </media:group>
    </item>
```